# Docker containers return error while creating on publishing server

Tags: c#, docker, selenium, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver

I developed a website using `Docker` for its backend side. There are some components such as `Selenium`, `Chrome Driver` and `MySQL` which are integrated in `docker-compose` file. The problem is that when I move my project to `VPS server` (CentOS), docker compose could not be created properly and returns the following error:

```
web_1           | crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
web_1           |       Application startup exception
web_1           |       OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown exception was encountered sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub/session. The exception message was: Connection refused (selenium-hub:4444)
web_1           |        ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (selenium-hub:4444)
web_1           |        ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
web_1           |          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
web_1           |          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
web_1           |          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The interesting point is that containers are created and run flawlessly in my local host, but when I run them on `VPS Server` I am faced with this error.
This is my `docker-compose` file:

```yaml
    version: "3"
    
    volumes:
      datafiles:
    
    services:
    
      database:
        image: mysql:8.0.28
        depends_on:
          - selenium-hub
        ports:
          - "3307:3306"
        volumes:
          - datafiles:/var/lib/mysql
          - "~/sql-scripts/setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql"
        restart: always
        environment: 
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
          MYSQL_USER: sa
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: ******
          MYSQL_DATABASE: Pan
    
      chrome:
        image: selenium/node-chrome:4.3.0-20220706
        shm_size: 2gb
        depends_on:
          - selenium-hub
        environment:
          - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
          - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
          - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
    
      selenium-hub:
        image: selenium/hub:4.3.0-20220706
        container_name: selenium-hub
        ports:
          - "4442:4442"
          - "4443:4443"
          - "4444:4444"  
      web:
         build: .
         ports: 
           - "8080:80"
         depends_on:
           - database
           - selenium-hub
           - chrome
         restart: always
```

And this is a piece of code I create my driver:

```cs
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
        options.AddArgument("headless");

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub"), options);
```

The way comes to my mind is that either I should modify my docker-compose file or give some permissions in `VPS server` to `Docker`.